# What tutorials or books are available for learning turn-based strategy game programming using HTML5?

Tags: ajax, html

I'm looking for tutorials/books/other resources for writing a HTML5 turn-based strategy game. I'd also be interested in any source code examples. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please checkout [html5gamedevs.com](http://www.html5gamedevs.com) ,this might help you.